# Require regular expression to validate a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression which will validate string of particular type.

The conditions to validate string are as follows:

- String should not contain characters like \ (backslash), / (forward
  slash), : (colon), * (asterisk), ? (question mark), " (double
  quotes), < (left angle bracket), > (right angle bracket), | (pipe)
- Do    not contain a hyphen (-) or a period (.) as the first or last
  character of a string.

I tried a lot but not getting any success as I require single regular expression fulfilling all conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/^[^.\-][^\/:*?"<>|]+[^.\-]$/
```

**Edit:** This regex should work:

```
/^(?![.\-])(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|])*[^.\-\\\/:*?"<>|]$/
```

But as you can see it gets pretty unreadable and ugly I think you'd be better off doing it in steps with a function like so:

```
function isValidString(str) {
  return /^[^.\-]/.test(str) &&
    /[^.\-]$/.test(str) &&
    /[^\\\/:*?"<>|]+/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot a backslash in the inner expression (e.g. [http://rubular.com/r/omHcHOBwXN](http://rubular.com/r/omHcHOBwXN) )

Comment: This won't check the first or last characters for `\/:*?"<>|`

Comment: You're both right let me check that and post a better regex. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Its not working based on my criteria

Comment: @elclanrs 100% working. Perfect Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression may contain so called "classes", predefined or custom sets of characters. Try with predefined like [:alpha:] or custom like [0-9*.><] and similar. Find out about class negation using "^" character, and escaping special characters by prepending them with "\".

Comment: Just FYI, `[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class, but JS' regex is more inspired by Perl.